# A noun followed by "the size of....."

Tags: sentence-construction

> NASA will launch a balloon ***the size of*** a football stadium into
> the stratosphere
> https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2020/07/24/nasa-launch-asthros-football-stadium-sized-balloon-stratosphere/5501605002/

> Rewilding Britain: the plan to restore an area ***the size of***
> Manchester
> https://www.positive.news/environment/the-plan-to-rewild-an-area-the-size-of-manchester/

Meaning of the both sentences above are clear, but is this sentence structure just common? If so, can I use the same sentence structure to describe something else like ***shape, length, color*** and so on?

For example, is my sentence below OK?

"Daddy, look at that!"  Shouted my little daughter, pointing her finger up in the sky. There was a big cloud ***the shape of*** Mickey Mouse.

Comment: Yes, you can. The use of such phrases is idiomatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here.

> https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/noun-the-size-of.3561160/
>
> The whole phrase "the size of ___" together works like an adjective,
> meaning "large" in these cases, although it could have been "small"
> with a different comparison like "a spider the size of a grain of
> salt" or "area of forest the size of my house". Other phrases for the
> same meaning are "the same size as {object}" and "as large/small as
> {object}". Another description with a different meaning but a similar
> structure (comparing one noun to another) is "a bird the color of
> strawberries".